Path integral for correlator of arbitrary initial and final states
I know that we can formulate a path integral for the correlator of the fields $\phi(x_1) \cdots \phi(x_n)$ as
$$
\langle 0 | T \left\{ \phi_I(x_1) \cdots \phi_I(x_n) \underset{\infty,-\infty}{U} \right\} | 0 \rangle
=\int D[\phi] \, \phi(x_1) \cdots \phi(x_n) e^{iS} \tag{1} \label{eq:1}.\\
$$
But suppose I was interested in an amplitude of the form
$$
\langle f | T \left\{ \phi_I(x_1) \cdots \phi_I(x_n) \underset{\infty,-\infty}{U} \right\} | i \rangle \tag{2}.
$$
For arbitrary initial and final states $|i\rangle$ and $|f\rangle$. Could this still be formulated as a path integral? If so, how would it differ from eq. \eqref{eq:1}?

Hint: It would impose initial and final conditions on the path integral (1).

For the $\langle 0| \dots |0 \rangle$ correlator, the boundary conditions are those for which $\phi(x_0=\infty)=0$. So for the $\langle f| \dots |i \rangle$ correlator (I guess) the boundary conditions would be non-zero in general, but I'm not sure what form they would take explicilty?
